# Get a random value from php array

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to PHP arrays and I have read about different approaches. I have a working jQuery page that relies on buttons being pressed. I'd like to continue using the buttons. I have come up with this code:

```
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.healthy_button').off('click').on('click', function(){

    " . $restChoice = array_rand($healthyRestaurants) . "

    console.log(\"restChoice =" . $healthyRestaurants[$restChoice] . "\");

    $('#result').html(\"Today, I suggest you eat at ---.\");
});
</script>
";
```

I keep getting an error that $restChoice is undefined as is the index in this line:
`console.log(\"restChoice =" . $healthyRestaurants[$restChoice] . "\");`

As you can see I'm trying to define it. Did I miss something obvious here?

Comment: Can you define variables mid string concatenation like that? (PHP isn't my game, but Im guessing no)

Comment: PHP executes on the server and sends unexecuted HTML and Javascript to the browser. Before sent you can inject values into your HTML and Javascript, but after that you no longer have direct access to the PHP in your page. To execute PHP you need to use your HTML or Javascript to send an HTTP POST (like a form) or GET (like a link). You can POST or GET by either reloading the page, or making a call to the server through an XHR object (AKA Ajax).

Comment: Have you tried moving `$restChoice = array_rand($healthyRestaurants)` above the `echo` statement and then only echo out `$restChoice`'s value?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - Im guessing this is executed at page render - which makes blending PHP into the JS possible, albeit ugly as sin.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles The issue is I would rather not reload the page, but have the answer instantly, and from my understanding you can't do that with a post or get, but again I am a php beginner. And yes, this is very ugly, but I did it this way because I knew no other way to mix the JS and the PHP.

Comment: I clarified the comment above. I remember starting out with server-side and client-side scripting and how it took a bit to figure out how they relate to each other.

Comment: @jkrehm The issue is I'd like a new value for $restChoice every time the button is pressed. If this happens outside the echo statement the value of $restChoice never changes.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Just to clarify, in general then, if you are dealing with a button press, as in this situation, then AJAX would be appropriate?

Comment: In this situation I think dumping the PHP array "down" to a Javascript array, then use Javascript to on-the-fly randomly pull restaurants form the list is a better option, unless you have hundreds of thousands of restaurants to pull from. See the response I left below. The point made above is that once the HTML and Javascript is loaded to the browser, you might call this Javascript execution mode, IF you need to execute a PHP script, or some other server script, you'll need to take special measures. There's a wall between PHP and Javascript. And they interact with each other differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a different restaurant every time the button is clicked, write the PHP restaurants array into a Javascript array. Then use Javascript to randomly pull restaurants when the button is clicked.

```
<?php

$healthyRestaurants = array(
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four",
  "Five"
);

?>

<button class="healthy_button">Restaurant</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

var hR = <?php echo json_encode($healthyRestaurants); ?>;

$('.healthy_button').on('click', function(){
    var rand_rest = hR[Math.floor(Math.random()*hR.length)];
    $('#result').html("Today, I suggest you eat at " + rand_rest);
});

</script>
```

PHP code cannot execute Javascript code and Javascript cannot execute PHP code. You can share information but if they had a facebook account their relationship status would be "it's complicated".

You can "hard-code" values from PHP "down" to Javascript. Javascript cannot reverse this. To get values back to PHP you must either reload the page or use an XHR object (AKA AJAX).

To minimize traffic and provide instant feedback for the user, use PHP to retrieve and write the restaurant array into a Javascript variable. Then use Javascript to randomly pull restaurants and write them to the screen.

Now if your list of restaurants is in the hundreds of thousands and the sheer amount is too much a burden to download to the browser, then an XHR object would make more sense.

Comment: I was just running through my code with this and I get this in the "result" p tag: `<p id="result">Today, I suggest you eat at [object Object]</p>`

Comment: Looks like we'll have to use something like `rand_rest.name`. But I don't know what the array keys are. What does `console.log(rand_rest)` after `var rand_rest...` output?

Comment: Perfect! It outputs the correct name. Thank you very much for your help. I need to figure out why .name was appropriate there. I know nothing about JS objects so I'll have to look into that. Thank you for sticking around. Despite looking around and reading what I could find, nothing was really helping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$healthyRestaurants` has been defined, define it outside of the `echo`:

```
$restChoice = array_rand($healthyRestaurants);

echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.healthy_button').off('click').on('click', function(){

    console.log(\"restChoice =" . $healthyRestaurants[$restChoice] . "\");

    $('#result').html(\"Today, I suggest you eat at ---.\");
});
</script>
";
```

Comment: Yes this is a possible method. $healthyRestaurants is defined above this text, however I would like the answer to be different with every click of the button. If $restChoice is generated outside the scope of the button press, it is determined at the page load and therefore remains the same every time the button is pressed. Correct?

Comment: @user2766423: Then your button click function will need to make an AJAX call to a PHP page that returns the array element.

Comment: Ok, I was unaware I would need an additional language. I assumed I would be able to achieve this with PHP and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Using a heredoc reduces the need for escaping in your text and makes it more readable...

I think your problem is you are getting JavaScript (+) and PHP (.) string concatenation confused.

```
$restChoice = array_rand($healthyRestaurants);
echo <<<EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.healthy_button').off('click').on('click', function(){

    {$restChoice}

    console.log("restChoice = {$healthyRestaurants[$restChoice]}");

    $('#result').html("Today, I suggest you eat at ---.");
});
</script>
EOF;
```